# High-performance C++ hash table implementation

Tags: open-source, software-development, c++

`std::unordered_map` is too slow for me. I want something faster! What libraries/stand-alone sources implement alternative, faster, hash maps with a similar (or superior) interface?

Requirements:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Some kind of testing to back claims of efficiency
- Non-negligable user base

Answer (score 2):

#### hopscotch

- Form: Header only
- License: MIT (Gratis and Libre)
- Performance benchmark results: [here](https://tessil.github.io/2016/08/29/benchmark-hopscotch-map.html)
- Git repository: [tessil/hopscotch-map](https://github.com/Tessil/hopscotch-map)

Hopscotch is also quite performant. I found it when I was looking for something similiar I used once so far a smaller project where it had far more better performance than std::unordered_map. I didn't do performance tests compared to the other competitors.

The header only library is available on GitHub, at the link above. The library also provides implementations of other hash map algorithms. The creator claims that it uses less memory than Google's `dense_hash_map` but has similiar performance. But as you can see from other posts here new hash map implementations pop up quite continously. According to a post I read hopscotch is supposed to be faster than the `ska::flat_hash_map`. Either way it is a lot faster than the maps in std.

Comment: Can you describe what's special about it? Who developed it? What's the motivation/context for its development? Why it's called that?

Comment: added some more details which I could find on a fast glimps and could recall from using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can sacrifice guarantees like reference stability, you can use

## [`ska::flat_hash_map`](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/blob/master/flat_hash_map.hpp) by Malte Skarupke

The main features are:

- [Open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing)
- [Linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing)
- [Robin-Hood hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Robin_Hood_hashing)
- Prime number amount of slots (but an option for using powers of two is provided)
- With an upper limit on the probe count

---

There is also a talk about it on YouTube given by Malte Skarupke at C++ Now 2018:

> [You Can Do Better than `std::unordered_map`: New Improvements to Hash Table Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2fKMP47slQ)

and blog posts on his personal blog where you can also find the benchmark picture below:

- https://probablydance.com/2017/02/26/i-wrote-the-fastest-hashtable/
- https://probablydance.com/2018/05/28/a-new-fast-hash-table-in-response-to-googles-new-fast-hash-table/

[image]

Comment: 1. Please write a couple of sentences about what's special with this hash map implementation, or what are its main design features; links are nice, but general policy on StackExchange is to have the basic information contained in the answer. 2. There are three different map headers at the link - how do they relate?

Comment: @einpoklum I added the main features listed in the blog to this post.  I don't think it is feasible to summarize a 1h 30min talk in a few sentences.  Only the `flat_hash_map.hpp` header is important, I changed the link.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [hash table shootout](http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html) page at incise.org.

According to that, the best performance - in terms of speed, not memory - is with Google's Dense Hash Map: [C++11 repository](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash-c11), [original repository](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash).

Note: The linked-to repositories are named "sparsehash", but actually contain both the sparse and dense hash maps, as well as sparse and dense hash sets.

Comment: The test is 8 years old - it might be worthwhile to revisit the numbers using current GCC.

Comment: In my more recent tests it is just as fast or faster than ska::flat_hash_map and F14 and both F14 and google dense are more memory efficient than ska::flat_hash_map: https://1ykos.github.io/patchmap/#Performance%20comparison

Comment: @WolfgangBrehm: What do you mean by "it"? I didn't mention "patchmap" in my answer... perhaps you could write a separate answer about your work?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm thinking about it, that's why I'm here, but it's not really the fastest haha. But I made benchmarks that compare the patchmap, google dense, F14, ska::flat_hash_map and many more, which you can find when you follow the link. The fastest hash tables have the lower most points, the most memory efficient ones are to the right.

Comment: @WolfgangBrehm: It doesn't have to be the fastest. The question is about hash maps faster than `std::unordered_map`. If it's interesting, and it seems to be - it merits an answer and probably an upvote.

Comment: @einpoklum Thank you for motivating me to add a recommendation, but what you probably really want is absl::flat_hash_map , the fastest with an actual userbase. Should I make another post for that too?

Comment: @WolfgangBrehm Yes. Although - are you sure it isn't a "recasting" of the older Google dense hash map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107944/discussion-between-wolfgang-brehm-and-einpoklum).

Answer (score 1):

## [patchmap](https://1ykos.github.io/patchmap/)

- [open source](https://github.com/1ykos/patchmap)
- gratis support from [me](https://github.com/1ykos/patchmap/issues)
- extensive performance tests and sparse unit tests
- almost perfectly mimicking the interface of `std::unordered_map`
- open addressing using linear probing with [pseudorandom ordering](http://alunos.dcc.ufla.br/index.php/INFOCOMP/article/view/581) (similar to Robin-Hood hashing)

I had a similar problem, I need a hash table that was not just faster but also more memory efficient, that's why I created the patchmap. The most relevant statistic when judging the performance of a hash table is the space-time trade-off. Both time and memory are costly resources, so you'll want to save them, but the preferred trade-off can differ.
[image: lookup performance and memory usage of different hash tables]

```
patchmap:                 khash: × 
bytell: +                   google::sparse_hash_map: ○ 
google::dense_hash_map: ⬟   ska::flat_hash_map: △ 
std::unordered_map: ◇       sparsepp: ◻     
Judy array: ◆               F14ValueMap: ▲ 
chaining+sorting: •         robin_hood::unordered_map: ▽  
absl::flat_hash_map: ⬠      tsl::sparse_hash_map: ★ 
emilib2::HashMap: ▩
```

Successful lookups are probably the most prevalent operation a hash table needs to perform, but insertion, deletion and failing lookup [benchmarks](https://1ykos.github.io/patchmap/#Performance%20comparison) do not change the picture dramatically. The patchmap is not the fastest. The fastest would be a hash table using lots of memory, a fast and good hash, and a simple open addressing and probing scheme like linear probing. It is also not the most memory efficient, although pseudorandom ordering can be [pushed](https://1ykos.github.io/patchmap/#Competing%20with%20google::sparse_hash_map) to that regime, sacrificing speed. It does however offer a small product of space and time, on par with [bytell](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/blob/master/bytell_hash_map.hpp), both only insignificantly better than [absl::flat_hash_map](https://abseil.io/blog/20180927-swisstables).

Comment: That is quite the informative chart :-)